# I can use SSML in the device_traits?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I want to know that SSML can be used with "name_synonym" of action.devices.Toggle or action.devices.traits.Mode.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/modes

{
  "availableModes": [{
    "name": "load",
    "name_values": [{
      **"name_synonym": ["load", "size", "load size"],**
      "lang": "en"
    }],

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question a bit more regarding what you are trying to achieve? SSML is generally used to programmatically determine how to generate speech output responses. The name values provided to a Modes trait are used to determine the grammar Google Assistant will parse from the user's speech input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SSML cannot be used as a `name_synonym`. The synonyms are used to map possible words or phrases the user says to a central key. So, the user may say "load", "size", etc. and you will get "load" on the backend.

As SSML is used for speech synthesis, not speech input, it would not be feasible to have SSML as one of the possible synonyms.

Comment: Thanks! your answer very helpful for me.